# Error while connecting sparklyr to remote sparkR in Rstudio

Tags: rstudio, sparklyr

I tried following command in my local RStudio session to connect to sparkR -

```
sc <- spark_connect(master = "spark://x.x.x.x:7077",
spark_home = "/home/hduser/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7", version="2.0.0", config = list())
```

But, I am getting following error -

```
Error in start_shell(master = master, spark_home = spark_home, spark_version = version,  : 
SPARK_HOME directory '/home/hduser/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7' not found
```

Any help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the `SPARK_HOME` environment variable set? I wonder if that's being selected for some reason?

Comment: I ran this command to set it -  Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = '/home/hduser/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7')

Answer (score 0):

may I ask you have you actually installed the spark into that folder?
Can you show the result of `ls` command in `/home/ubuntu/` folder?

And `sessionInfo()` in R?

Let me please share with you how I am using the custom folder structure.
It is on Win, not Ubuntu but I guess it won't make much of the difference.

#### Using the most recent dev edition

If you would check on GitHub the RStudio guys are updating sparklyr almost every day fixing numerous reported bugs:

> devtools::install_github("rstudio/sparklyr")

in my case only installation of `sparklyr_0.4.12` has resolved problem with Spark 2.0 under Windows

#### Checking Spark availability

please check if version you're inquiring is available:

> spark_available_versions()

You should see something like the line below, which indicates that the version you indend to use is actually available for your sparklyr package.

> [13] 2.0.0  2.7  spark_install(version = "2.0.0", hadoop_version = "2.7")

#### Installation of Spark

Just to keep the order you may like to install spark in other location rather then home folder of RStudio cache.

> options(spark.install.dir = "c:/spark")

Once you are sure the desire version is available it is time to install spark

> spark_install(version = "2.0.0", hadoop_version = "2.7")

I'd check if it is install correctly (change it for shell `ls` if needed)

> cd c:/spark
>   dir (in Win) | ls (in Ubuntu)

Now specify the location of the edition you want to use:

> Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = 'C:/spark/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7')

And finally enjoy the creation of connection:

> sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")

I hope it helps.